# Is there any way to apply FocusPanel in GWT with more than one Child widget

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I wish to add the mouseover events to a panel which contains more than one child widget in it. When i tried it with FocusPanel i was halted by the exception "SimplePanel can only contain one child widget". Is there any other way i can use mouse over events over the panel with multiple child widgets?
For Example in the following code

`<g:FocusPanel ui:field="parent"><childwidget1/><childwidget2/><childwidget3/><g:FocusPanel>`

I need to add mouseover events to the parent panel. Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a child `FlowPanel` (or whichever panel laying out several widgets, depending on your layout needs) in between the `FocusPanel` and child widgets:

```
<g:FocusPanel ui:field="parent">
  <g:FlowPanel>
    <my:childwidget1/>
    <my:childwidget2/>
    <my:childwidget3/>
  </g:FlowPanel>
</g:FocusPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It worked and sorry for being so dumb as i m new to GWT.

Comment: Strangely enough, if not using UIBinder, GWT doesn't throw any exception, it simply doesn't show anything! I tumbled across this, only then did I realize that the problem is adding more than 1 child..